# Removing layers from OpenLayers not working after layers are drawn

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a simple map application written with Angular and Node.js
There is search service that works fine and shows the results with geometry.
After the search results I draw each result on map
So far everything is fine.
But after each result, I have to remove the old layers drawn on the map which I can not do it.

Here is my code:

```
onSearch(params: any) {
   if (params.target.value !== "") {
       this.httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:3001/search?q=' + params.target.value).subscribe((response: any) => {
       this.searchResults = response
       this.mapService._map.removeLayer(this.vectorPolygon) // removing layers
       this.drawLocation(this.searchResults) // draw new ones
       return response
    })
   } else {
       this.searchResults = []
    }
}
drawLocation(results: any) {
results.map(res => {
  const format = new ol_format()
  const feature = format.readFeature(res._source.st_astext, {
    dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
    featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
  })
  this.vectorSource = new ol_source_vector({
    features: [feature]
  })
  this.vectorPolygon = new ol_layer_vector({
    source: this.vectorSource,
    displayInLayerSwitcher: false,
    style: this.styleMe(feature)
  })
  this.mapService._map.addLayer(this.vectorPolygon)
})
}
```

Comment: Define/create your vector layer and it's source outside `drawLocation` only once. Then before adding newly created feature to the vector source with `.addFeature(feature)` method, you can remove previous feature with the `.clear()' method.

Comment: Thanks, should I use `.addFeature(feature)` because I didnt use it in my code.